# How to prove that the $n+1$ th fibonacci number is given by these formulae?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

$$F(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\left( \frac{n+2k}{2}\right)!}{(2k)!\left( \frac{n-2k}{2}\right)!}$$
if $n$ is even

$$F(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\left( \frac{n+2k+1}{2}\right)!}{(2k+1)!\left( \frac{n-2k-1}{2}\right)!}$$

if $n$ is odd

And, I've assumed the Fibonacci sequence to be this: $1,1,2,3,5.....$, i.e. without a $0$ in the beginning. Can these formulas be proved?

Comment: What does induction tell you?  The first sum can be expressed in sigma notation as follows: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\left(\frac{n+2k}{2}\right)!}{(2k)!\left(\frac{n-2k}{2}\right)!}.$$  Try it on your own for the second sum.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh, that's awesome. I think in the second formula, I should replace $k$ by $2k+1$ and let $k$ vary from $0$ to $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: In the second one, your upper limit might be something like $\frac{n-1}{2}$ since $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Show that $F(n + 1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$ and check if the first two elements of $F(n)$ coincide with the first two elements of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.